# Is it possible to install a Wear OS apk from an Android phone?

Tags: apk, android-wear

I develop Wear OS apps and watchfaces at home with Android Studio, then use adb to install them to a physical watch.

I'm currently on a trip, and connected to my home development machine (via my travel Android tablet and Teamviewer) so I can continue development -- but since I'm not on my home WiFi, I can't use adb to transfer the apk.

Is there any way to do this? I can get the compiled apk onto my phone via gmail or gdrive, but don't know of any way to move it to my watch.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can't you use an USB cable?

Comment: This question is off-topic on Android Enthusiasts, because it is a development question.